# Grep more than one string in a single line

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to locate two strings in a single line. Below is the example line.

```
line1: xxxx yyyy time1-12 zzzz time2-13
line2: xxxx yyyy time1-14 zzzz time2-15
```

I am using the below grep command to achieve this

```
grep -o -E 'time1-[0-9]*|time2-[0-9]*' timetest.txt
```

This is giving me the output as

```
time1-12
time2-13
time1-14
time2-15
```

But i want like this

```
time1-12 time2-13
time1-14 time2-15
```

What i am missing here? Can i go for awk or sed for getting this output

Comment: try `awk '{print $4 " " $6}' timetest.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/time1-[0-9]*/,a) && match($0,/time2-[0-9]*/,b) { print a[0], b[0] }' file
time1-12 time2-13
time1-14 time2-15
```

Note that time1 and time2 can be in any order on the line. With other awks you need to use substr() to extract the match() results:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/time1-[0-9]*/) && (a=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)) && match($0,/time2-[0-9]*/) { print a, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) }' file
time1-12 time2-13
time1-14 time2-15
```

If the 2 times are always in the same order then with gawk you could do:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(time1-[0-9]*).*(time2-[0-9]*)/,a) { print a[1], a[2] }' file
time1-12 time2-13
time1-14 time2-15
```

but then it's just a simple substitution on an individual line so you may as well just use sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*(time1-[0-9]*).*(time2-[0-9]*).*/\1 \2/' file
time1-12 time2-13
time1-14 time2-15
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -lne 'print "$1 $2" if /(time1-[0-9]+).*(time2-[0-9]+)/' timetest.txt
```

The code assumes `time1` comes always before `time2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this sed command ,

```
sed 's/[^t]\+\(time[^ ]\+\)/\1 /g' FileName
```

or

```
sed 's/[^t]\+\(time\(1\|2\)[^ ]\+\)/\1 /g' FileName
```

**OutPut:**

```
time1-12 time2-13 
time1-14 time2-15
```

`Cut` version

```
cut -d" " -f 4,6 FileName
```

Comment: That just prints the end of any line that contains a string that starts with `time`, it doesn't look for the 2 specific regexps the OP cares about.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using `grep`

```
grep -o -E 'time[0-9]+-[0-9]+' timetest.txt | paste -d " " - -
```

you get,

```
time1-12 time2-13
time1-14 time2-15
```

Comment: That was my though too. Only difficulty: if there are not 2 matches on every line, the output may merge matches from different lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -vRS="time[12]-[0-9]+" '{$0=RT}1' filename
time1-12
time2-13
time1-14
time2-15
```